# Chrome USB API - How do I get the ConnectionHandle

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, usb, google-chrome-app

I've been looking at USB Api to connect to a USB relay.

Using chrome.usb.findDevices I can open the device but then I need to send some data to it. I'm thinking chrome.usb.controlTransfer is the way to do that. I have no idea how to get the ConnectionHandle which I need for the next step.

My findDevices code is below.

Any help would be gratefully received. I'm properly confused.

```
var usbConnection;

var onOpenCallback = function(connection) {
  if (connection) {
    usbConnection = connection;
    document.getElementById("found").innerHTML ="Device opened.";

  } else {
    document.getElementById("found").innerHTML ="Device failed to open.";
  }
}; 

chrome.usb.findDevices(DEVICE_INFO, onOpenCallback);
```

Comment: I think the answers posted here: https://groups.google.com/a/chromium.org/forum/#!topic/chromium-apps/ikIMV_o2Yqs is quite clear now. If you have any further concerns about it, you should update your issue content.

Answer (score 0):

After getting a `Device` by calling `chrome.usb.findDevices`, another API `chrome.usb.openDevice` should be issued to open the USB port.